# Como ejecutar una funcion sincronicamente en JS?

Tags: javascript, asincronismo, vanilla

JS: Tengo una lista de ids, que debo de enviar a consultar un servidor y requiero realizar la consulta uno por uno, con la condición de que si no se ha terminado la consulta del anterior no pueda consultar el siguiente.

```js
function mgnGetMultiPages(ids){
  ids.forEach(function (item) {
    let obj = document.getElementById(item);
      console.log('procesando ', item);
      mngProcessPage(obj.dataset);
    }
  );
}
```

Que me recomiendan implementar?

Comment: Pero si ese código parece sincrono. ¿Asincrono querrás decir? O la función mngProcessPage es asincrona?